# mysql writing speed to disk

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm working in mysql community version 5.6 with a 60 millions record database, and I have to create (is not optional) a table with a select instruction using the only table in the DB, but the process is to slow because mysql only write to disk around 4096kb per second, is there a way to change this parameter, with this perfomance the full process could take like 6 hours, and several times in the middle I get errors like 1025 exceed lock time.

I tried:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
SET unique_checks=0;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

The buffer pool is set to 11G.

The database size is around 35GB, the expected output must around 25GB.

Comment: mysql doesn't have a bandwidth limiter. if it's slow writing to disk, it's because your system's disk is slow...

Comment: time to upgrade the single disk/raid1 machine to raid10 and/or use ssd's.

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, there's an **`innodb_io_capacity`** system variable you should be aware of. Reference: [**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-thread_io_rate.html**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-thread_io_rate.html) . In earlier versions of MySQL (like 5.1) this was a fixed limit, which was compiled into the code. The setting in MySQL 5.6 is configurable; the default setting might be set too low.